# disable _ttl for old documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index and enabled automatic retention of documents using the "_ttl"-feature. The ttl works as a charm but it has been discovered that the data was quite valuable and has to be kept.

I've tried to make a snapshot and then restore it but with no luck.
My last resort would be to fetch all documents and re-insert them, but that is a bit cumbersome. Can I disable _ttl in any nicer way for my old documents?

Elasticsearch version: 1.7.3

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `IndicesTTLService` class has a property called `index.ttl.disable_purge` ([link to the code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/dcfdc0dbf32f766aba2af5c0e5fd7f2d302f4af2/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/indices/ttl/IndicesTTLService.java#L70)). Try to set that property to true. If you don't know how to update indices settings [this is the link to the api doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-update-settings.html)

A plan B would be set the refresh interval (property `indices.ttl.interval`) to a really big value.

Comment: 'index.ttl.disable_purge' is flagged as experimental so feels like it's a bit risky to depend on it since it can be removed at any time.

'indices.ttl.interval' looks to be a cluster wide setting which I want to avoid.

Comment: Well, ttl field is already deprecated in 2.0.0 so, maybe it's not that risky to use `index.ttl.disable_purge`. In any case I think reindexing your documents would be the safest solution.